# Unable to fetch correct updated value after transaction in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this firebase schema
[image]

The front-end of my application is in react and backend is in node.
Whenever a user registers in my application I am incrementing `totalUsers` count by 1 using firebase transactions, after that I am fetching and then putting it inside `users`. 
Here is the code for fetching the data:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
        .then(authUser => {
            console.log(db);
            console.log(authUser.uid);
            // Create user in FirebaseDB
                var value = 0;
                let generate_id = db.ref(`totalUsers`);
                generate_id.transaction((current_value) => {
                    return current_value + 1;
                });
                generate_id.on("value", (data) => {
                    value = data.val();
                    console.log(`Data: ${data.val()}`);
                });
                console.log(`Value: ${value}`);
                db.ref(`/users/${authUser.uid}`).set({
                    name,
                    email,
                    college,
                    dob,
                    gender,
                    sam_id
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.setState({
                        name: '',
                        email: '',
                        passwordOne: '',
                        passwordTwo: '',
                        college: '',
                        dob: '',
                        gender: ''
                    })
                    history.push('/');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert(error);
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

This is what I am getting in my console:
[image]

The problem is I am not able to get the latest updated value in totalUsers and I am new to firebase. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get number of users, you may retrieve the total user number as fallow:

```
if (signedin) {
  firebase.database().ref('users').on('value', u => {
     this.totalUsers = Object.values(u.val()).length; 
     console.log("Number of Total Users: "+ this.totalUsers );
  })
}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to set a unique user id, for that I am incrementing user count and then using that count to set id. For example: if someone registers then i increment user count and then use it to set user id in users like 'SAM18001'.